Received error while deploying Bicep. Error: "The role assignment request schedule is invalid. (InvalidRoleAssignmentRequestSchedule)"
I'm utilizing Bicep to enable Azure AD Privileged Identity Management (PIM) with a custom role. I've created an AD Group and assigned a Custom Role to it, which includes the following actions:
"Microsoft.Authorization//read", "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/read", "Microsoft.Support/"

Upon deploying the resources using Bicep and Azure PowerShell commands, I encountered the following error:

The role assignment request schedule is invalid. (InvalidRoleAssignmentRequestSchedule)

To troubleshoot, I verified whether the service account has the necessary permissions to deploy Bicep and found that it has owner-level access.
Powershell script
$deploymentName = (Get-Date).ToString('yyyyMMdd-HHmm')New-AzDeployment -Name $deploymentName -Location northcentralus -TemplateFile .\pim.bicep -TemplateParameterFile .\agdev-PreProd.parameters.json

Bicep
targetScope = 'subscription'

param startTime string = utcNow()

@description('Object Id of the AD Group')
param principalId string = ''

@description('Custom role definition ID being assigned to the AD group')
param roleDefinitionId string = ''

@description('Unique name for the roleAssignment in the format of a guid')
var roleName = guid(principalId, roleDefinitionId, subscription().id)

resource pimRoleAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleEligibilityScheduleRequests@2022-04-01-preview' = {
  name: roleName
  scope: subscription()
  properties: {
    principalId: principalId
    requestType: 'AdminAssign'
    roleDefinitionId: resourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', roleDefinitionId)
    scheduleInfo: {
      startDateTime: startTime
    }
  }
}


I've identified a solution by utilizing the requestType "NoExpiration," allowing for a permanent role assignment. However, before proceeding, I must remove the role currently assigned to "Eligible" in PIM. Upon attempting to do so with the below Bicep script, I encountered an error indicating an "incorrect segment length for "roleAssignmentName". It appears that a nested resource type must match the number of segments in its resource group name". Could you please advise on the appropriate method to remove the existing role assignment using Bicep, PowerShell, or Azure CLI?

BICEP
targetScope = 'subscription'
@description('Role Assignment Id of the CustomRole Assigned to the AD Grp')
param roleAssignmentId string = ''
@description('Object Id of the AD Group')
param principalId string = ''
@description('Role Definition Id of the Custom Role')
param roleDefinitionId string = ''
resource pimRoleAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleEligibilityScheduleRequests@2022-04-01-preview' = {
name: roleAssignmentId
scope: subscription()
properties: {
principalId: principalId
roleDefinitionId: roleDefinitionId
requestType: 'AdminRemove'
}
}


Could you please advise on the appropriate method to remove the existing role assignment using Bicep, PowerShell, or Azure CLI:

After trying the changes given by you in the Bicep code, I was able to achieve the similar output as you detailed in your comment.
But now according to your ask regarding "remove the existing role assignment using PowerShell or CLI", use below PowerShell commands.
PowerShell:
I have tried to remove a sample custom role which was created earlier and was able to perform it successfully as shown below.
$get = Get-AzRoleAssignment -Scope "/subscriptions/subscriptionID/resourcegroups/Resourcegroup" -RoleDefinitionName "samplerole"
Remove-AzRoleAssignment -Scope $get.Scope -ObjectId $get.ObjectId -RoleDefinitionName $get.RoleDefinitionName

Output:

With CLI, use command az role assignment to perform the similar operations as above.

Thank you, Jahnavi, for the update. However, I have a question. If I am using the above BICEP for removing the Eligible role assignment from PIM, what should be my approach? The BICEP I am deploying seems to only create the Eligible Assignment. Could you guide me on the process to remove it?

Also right now iam trying to use BICEP for Eligible Role Assignment but it should have NoExpiration policy. When i use the below BICEP, i received the following error
Error: code: RoleAssignmentRequestPolicyValidationFailed
message: The following policy rules failed: ["ExpirationRule"]
BICEP
scheduleInfo: {
expiration: {
duration: 'P365D'
type: 'NoExpiration'
}
startDateTime: startTime
}

I have checked for the solution in the below link under Common Errors returned for a new request: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/authorization/privileged-role-eligibility-rest-sample. Where the explanation was given as The ScheduleInfo specified in the request exceeds the maximum allowed duration. In this case do we need to provide mandatory expiry date to 'P180D' which will resolve this error?

Yes we can try adding manually. Did you give a try ? @CharismaticDevelop

I have tried to add the schedule info with the expiry date duration to null. Even though i received the same error

So as I mentioned above, the limit is already set by default and it might not be possible to exceed it. @CharismaticDevelop

OK @Jahnavi. Let me add the duration to P180D and see whether its deploying then i will update you accordingly

Hi @Jahnavi. I have made the changes of PIM role settings to Permanent Eligible and deployed the bicep with the request type as NoExpiration and the issue is resolved. Right now iam able to create PIM Eligible Assignment using Bicep. Thank you

Also i have one more doubt regards to the change of PIM role settings i have done manually through portal. Is there any option to make this changes using PowerShell script or it needs to be done manually through Portal only
